# What goes with people after their death?

Tags: death

It is being said that we have come empty handed in the world and we will return (after death) empty handed. Only our Karma goes with us.

My question is - How true it the above statement ?
I mean - Does only our Karma accompany us or does out memories that we made in this life also go with us ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's true. Only the good Karmas that we perform here on earth are our friend after we die. As one verse given below says, the good Karmas that we accumulate in the current life are our only friend in the next life.

> Manu Smriti 4.238. Giving no pain to any creature, let him slowly
> accumulate spiritual merit, for the sake (of acquiring) a companion to
> the next world, just as the white ant (gradually raises its) hill.
>
> 4.239. **For in the next world** neither father, nor mother, nor wife, nor sons, nor relations stay to be his companions; **spiritual merit
> alone remains (with him).**
>
> 4.240. Single is each being born; single it dies; single it enjoys (the reward of its) virtue; single (it suffers the punishment of its)
> sin.

Answer (score 1):

To put it in factual terms it's not called karma, saints and pandits have been passing along the wrong word or I say some lack of correct words, to put in terms of Veda's and it is actually called prarabdha karma (प्रारब्ध).

Well, there are many definitions and meanings to it along with prarabdha-gati, and prarabhdha-yoga. It is the collection of all the good and bad deeds done with the current incarnated body and spirit goes with you. It's not just good karma. And it is to be believed that you have to pay off the balance with sorrow, pain and happiness, joy etcetera. in the next incarnated body.

I know there is some confusion among the people that only good karma goes but what I know of that is the Prarabdha does its work in the afterlife including both good and bad deeds.